# IBM Worklight - App displays properly in browser but not when previewing in the MBS

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console, worklight-mbs

I am writing a Worklight Hybrid application and utilizing jQuery Mobile in it.

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/itemDetails.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/itemDetails.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page" id="detailsPage">
     <div data-role="header" id="itemDetailsNavBar">
     <a href="#leftPanel" data-role="ui-icon-list-panel" data-corners="false" id="listButtonLeft"></a>
     <h1>Item Details</h1>
     <a href="index.html" data-role="ui-icon-edit" data-corners="false" id="editButtonRight"></a>
     </div>
    </div> 

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script>
<script src="modules/core/MenuPanel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";


#itemDetailsNavBar
{
    background: #ffb400 !important;
    height: 44px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#listButtonLeft {
    background: transparent url("images/list.png");
    box-shadow: none;
    data-corners :"false";
    margin-top: 19px;
    border: none;    
}

#editButtonRight {
    background: transparent url("images/edit.png");
    box-shadow: none;
    data-corners :"false";
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: none;
}
```

**When previewing in a browser I see it properly:**

[image]

**But when previewing via Worklight Console's MBS, this is what I am getting:**

[image]

Comment: What is `data-corners :"false"` supposed to do?

Comment: For removing the rounded corners I guess.

Comment: Well that should not be in the css, since it's not a css rule. You should only use that as an html attribute which it seems you already have.

Comment: Removed it from CSS, no use!

Comment: This is Worklight 6.0, right? There is already jquery built-in, you do not need to include this line: <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> -- it is also not jquery mobile, so why put it in that folder? also, this file is not even being used because you did not remove the line above it, which means that the app is still using the built-in jquery.

Comment: Also your CSS does not contain any special characters, why do you specify the @charset in it?

Comment: What do you mean "in the browser". How do you preview it?

Comment: Also, that is not the iOS Simulator, but Worklight Console's MBS. Open the chrome dev tools and check if there are any errors.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in the MBS.  Just a few notes:  As Idan said, you should either have the line importing WL's jQuery, or import your own jQuery, but not both.  Do you really mean to be using HTML 4.0.1?  Are you using Chrome or FireFox, and do you have Useragent Switching enabled in the MBS?

Comment: @IdanAdar I used chrome and safari to preview it. If I remove the Jquery import line then Jquery does not seem to work, I mean it gives me Cant Find variable $.

Comment: Upload your project somewhere so it can be downloaded and examined.

Comment: @IdanAdar https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll9yo1t0wav8tvu/common.zip ,let me know.

Comment: No, this is not good. Export the Worklight PROJECT from Eclipse, otherwise I cannot build it.

Comment: @IdanAdar I found the issue, it is because of the CSS. If I add styles directly to html they seem to work fine.

Comment: @satheeshwaran, That's weird... then there is an issue with the way you link your CSS to the HTML. Can you please write this as an answer?

Comment: @IdanAdar I fixed the issue, will post the answer right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the CSS from the head and added it just before the body end tag and everything seems to work fine both in simulator and the MBS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    </head>
    <body >
        <div data-role="page" id="detailsPage">
         <div data-role="header" id="itemDetailsNavBar">
         <a href="#leftPanel" data-role="ui-icon-list-panel" data-corners="false" id="listButtonLeft"></a>
         <h1>Item Details</h1>
         <a href="index.html" data-role="ui-icon-edit" data-corners="false" id="editButtonRight"></a>
         </div>
        </div> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/itemDetails.css">
   <script src="js/itemDetails.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```